# how to use log4j in Multithread using java?

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

I want to write log for each thread using log4j and log file name will be "workthread..log",first thread print log on file "workthread-1.log" and second thread on "workthread-2.log" and so on.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable 
  {
       private Logger logger=null;

       public MyRunnable()
        {
            DOMConfigurator.configure(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(LOG4J_FILEPATH));
            logger =Logger.getLogger(classname);
        }

        public void run() 
        {
          logger.info("Important job running in MyRunnable"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
   }


public class TestThreads 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
     {
        Thread[] worker=new Thread[3];
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
           worker[i]=new Thread(r);
           worker[i].start();
        }


    }
}//class
```

please help me?

Regards

Comment: and what is your problem? what is the code doing? is there any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you could try somezthing like this:

```
logger = Logger.getLogger(classname);
logger.removeAllAppenders();                                        
logger.addAppender(new FileAppender(layout, "your-thread-name.log", true));
```

you could get the name of your thread with something like "thread.getName()" i think ;)

Answer (score 4):

you could use MDC

MDC.put(key,value); --in the code

and %X{key}-- in the file name field in the log4j configuration file

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize each `logger` field with an instance by using [`LogManager.getLogger(Class)` method](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.html#getLogger%28java.lang.Class%29). By using different text file appenders, you can dump the log lines to an appropriately names text file.

In case each thread used an own `Runnable` implementation (?), this should work. If it doesn't, try using a `ThreadLocal<Logger>` as `logger` and fill it by using `LogManager.getLogger(String)` with a Thread-widely unique name.

See also [Short introduction to log4j: Ceki Gülcü, March 2002](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) in case you need an example of how to configure appenders.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement a new log appender which manages FileAppender for different thread and files. Use AppenderSkeleton to do this, maintain a map for FileAppenders.

   ```
   public MultiThreadAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
       public final static String THREAD_KEY = "THREAD_NO";
       private Map<String, FileAppender> fileAppenders;
   }
   ```
2. Use MDC to identify different threads. Use a key like "THREAD_NO", put to MDC (MDC.put) when a thread invoke logger the first time, and check this key to get the FileAppender for it. Here's the example:

   ```
   protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
       Object value = event.getMDC(THREAD_KEY);
       FileAppender appender;
       if (value instanceof String && ((String) value).length() > 0) {
           appender = fileAppenders.get(value);
       } else {
           value = nextThreadNo();
           fileAppenders.put(value, new FileAppender(...)); //
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I use thread specific logger. Just copy paste and it on top of you run method and should work as is. Don't forget to change the text in caps.

```
String currenttime = String.valueOf(new Long(new Date().getTime()/1000));
String logFileName = "NAMEHERE_thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() 
                     + "_" + currenttime+".log";
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NAMEHERE_thread" +
                                      Thread.currentThread().getId() + "_"+ currenttime);

Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("log4j.logger.NAMEHERE_thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() 
                 + "_" + currenttime,"DEBUG, file");

prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.file", "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender");
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize", "100MB");
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex", "100");
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.file.File", 
                 REPLACEMEWITHPATH + File.separator + logFileName);
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.file.threshold","debug");
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.file.layout", "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern", 
                 "%d [%t] %-5p [%-35F : %-25M : %-6L] %-C -%m%n");
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout", "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender");
PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
```