# Synchronised Logging for Log4j

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

I have a multithreaded application and I use Log4j for Logging. The problem I face is that the Logs are appended as soon as they are triggered. So the logs of different threads are coming as they are triggered. All I need is the logs triggered from a method of a class to have its logs together even if they are called at later point of time.

Comment: There are tons of answers to this question, please use the search function first before starting a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging in multi-threaded application in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109140/logging-in-multi-threaded-application-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use Asynchronous Logging, in log4j.xml try something like

```
<appender name="messages" class="FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="messages.log"/>
</appender>

<appender name="messages-async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
    <appender-ref ref="messages"/>
</appender>

<logger name="messages" additivity="false">
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="messages-async"/>
</logger>
```

Alternatively, have a look at [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/index.html).